# Does Coinbase have the ability to create a "Business" Account?

Tags: coinbase.com

Wanted to see if anyone here knew if you are able to work with Coinbase to create a "Business/Corporate" level Accounts?

Meaning that when signing up and linking a bank account to your Coinbase account you could choose to use your Business bank account, and verify using an EIN instead of a personal SSN?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I'm with Coinbase ([proof](https://community.coinbase.com/users/johnmardlin/activity)), better late than never with this answer.

We do have a way of doing this now, though it requires some extra verification steps to properly link your account to the business entity.

Email us at support@coinbase.com

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any similar option in [Merchant Profile](https://www.coinbase.com/merchants).

If you live in USA maybe [Circle](https://www.circle.com/en) will help you.